# Sequelize altering a table that counts based on a relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, orm, sequelize.js

So I have the following table:

```
VoucherID    VoucherBatch
1            v001
2            v001
3            v001
4            v002
5            v002
6            v002
7            v003
```

And I wanted to add a column to indicate the voucher that voucher's number in that batch, the expected result would be like this

```
VoucherID    VoucherBatch   VoucherEdition
1            v001           1
2            v001           2
3            v001           3
4            v002           1
5            v002           2
6            v002           3
7            v003           1
```

Does sequelize support something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select this "voucherEdition" column using ROW_NUMBER(), here the query:

```
SELECT voucherid, voucherbatch,   
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY voucherbatch) AS voucherEdition 
FROM vouchers;
```

If you only need this select, you're done. Otherwise you can create the new voucherEdition column:

```
ALTER TABLE vouchers ADD COLUMN voucherEdition INT;
```

and then fill this new column using the mentioned query, so the update command will look like this:

```
UPDATE vouchers v JOIN
(SELECT voucherid,  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY voucherbatch) AS voucherEdition 
FROM vouchers) x ON v.voucherid = x.voucherid
SET v.voucherEdition = x.voucherEdition;
```

Here I created an example, so you can see this is working correctly: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b4b52fdc3a2cc7773b00f6bb16315be)